# Java 2D Game Key Input (Best Practice?)

Tags: java, input, keypress, slick2d, 2d-games

I'm brand new to game development and have chosen to start working on a 2D top-down scroller game. I'm using the Slick2D library for this game.

My question is about best practices for taking multiple direction input for sprite movement (UP + RIGHT = Diagonal)

Currently, I have a rather ugly looking if/elseif chain to read in the input from the keyboard that is then checked in the 'Mob' class to determine how the sprite will move. The current setup works just fine, but my question is if there is another, better way of going about taking multiple inputs for diagonals (or any combo of keys, for that matter)

Here is the main class's update method that reads the input (blooper is the instance of 'Mob'):

```
public void update(GameContainer container, StateBasedGame arg1, int delta) throws SlickException {
    Input input = container.getInput();


    if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {          //RIGHT
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){          //RIGHT + UP
            blooper.direction = 2;
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){ //RIGHT + DOWN
            blooper.direction = 3;
        }
        else {
            blooper.direction = 1;
        }
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){     //LEFT
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){          //LEFT + UP
            blooper.direction = 5;
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){ //LEFT + DOWN
            blooper.direction = 6;
        } else{
            blooper.direction = 4;
        }
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){       //UP
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){       //UP + RIGHT
            blooper.direction = 8;
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){ //UP + LEFT
            blooper.direction = 9;
        } else{
            blooper.direction = 7;
        }
    } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){     //DOWN
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){       //DOWN + RIGHT
            blooper.direction = 11;
        } else if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){ //DOWN + LEFT
            blooper.direction = 12;
        } else{
            blooper.direction = 10;
        }
    } else{
        blooper.direction = -1;
    }

    blooper.update(delta);

}
```

And here is how that input is processed in the Mob class:

```
public class Mob {

private final int RIGHT     = 1;
private final int RIGHTUP   = 2;
private final int RIGHTDOWN = 3;
private final int LEFT      = 4;
private final int LEFTUP    = 5;
private final int LEFTDOWN  = 6;
private final int UP        = 7;
private final int UPRIGHT   = 8;
private final int UPLEFT    = 9;
private final int DOWN      = 10;
private final int DOWNRIGHT = 11;
private final int DOWNLEFT  = 12;
private final int IDLE      = -1;

int direction = IDLE;

int x, y;
Image sprite;

public Mob() throws SlickException{
    x = 20;
    y = 20;
    sprite = new Image("res/blooper.png");
}

public void update(int delta){
    move();
}

public void draw(){
    sprite.draw(x, y);
}

public void move(){

    switch(direction){
        case RIGHT:
            x += 1;
            break;
        case RIGHTUP:
            x += 1;
            y -= 1;
            break;
        case RIGHTDOWN:
            x += 1;
            y += 1;
            break;          
        case LEFT:
            x -= 1;
            break;
        case LEFTUP:
            x -= 1;
            y -= 1;
            break;
        case LEFTDOWN:
            x -= 1;
            y += 1;
            break;
        case UP:
            y -= 1;
            break;
        case UPRIGHT:
            y -= 1;
            x += 1;
            break;
        case UPLEFT:
            y -= 1;
            x -= 1;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y += 1;
            break;
        case DOWNRIGHT:
            y += 1;
            x += 1;
            break;
        case DOWNLEFT:
            y += 1;
            x -= 1;
            break;
        case IDLE:
            //nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said...this works, but doesn't seem like the best way to go about it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Make left/right and up/down movement independent. You (or the framework - I'm unfamiliar with it) seems to work with x/y coordinates, which are mathematically independent.
Thus make one function that treats the up/down movement, and one function that treats the left/right movement, and you can get rid of their 'combinations'. Is there a reason why the directions are positive integers? Try making left = -1, right = 1, and no x-direction movement 0, and then do the same for y. That should hopefully make it more intuitive.

Happy coding

Comment: Thanks for the advice - not sure why I was trying to combine them to a single move() method. This should work - I'll work out the changes and give you an update! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Make a `blooper.direction` a bitwise, like:

```
blooper.direction=0;
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) blooper.direction|=1;
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) blooper.direction|=2;
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) blooper.direction|=4;
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) blooper.direction|=8;
```

then in `move` do the move, like:

```
if ((blooper.direction&1)!=0) x+=1;
if ((blooper.direction&2)!=0) x-=1;
if ((blooper.direction&4)!=0) y-=1;
if ((blooper.direction&8)!=0) y+=1;
```

Comment: I love this more minimalistic approach. I will see if I can implement this and give you an update. Thanks!